# How to improve `FindDistribution`?

Tags: performance-tuning, distributions

```
Table[{n, FindDistribution[RandomSample[
    Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[k, Binomial[n, k]], {k, 0, n}]
], TargetFunctions -> "Discrete"]}, {n, 15}] // TableForm
```

returns this table:

```
1   BinomialDistribution[1,0.5]
2   BinomialDistribution[2,0.5]
3   BinomialDistribution[4,0.375]
4   BinomialDistribution[5,0.4]
5   BinomialDistribution[6,0.416667]
6   BinomialDistribution[7,0.428571]
7   BinomialDistribution[8,0.4375]
8   BinomialDistribution[8,0.5]
9   BinomialDistribution[10,0.450662]
10  BinomialDistribution[11,0.441601]
11  BinomialDistribution[12,0.461921]
12  BinomialDistribution[12,0.500552]
13  BinomialDistribution[13,0.512226]
14  BinomialDistribution[18,0.384842]
15  BinomialDistribution[16,0.473303]
```

But in fact the data provided should give in the $n$th row `BinomialDistribution[n,0.5]` since the frequencies literally coincide with those corresponding to the probability formula $\binom nk(0.5)^n$. In some cases (for $n=1,2,8,12$) the answer is very close to it, but in many others quite far. Why?

Can one do something to achieve better results?

Comment: You have not described what you are trying to accomplish. Just given the code, we have no way of knowing why it isn't satisfactory.

Comment: @BobHanlon You are right, sorry - will add that

Comment: The main issue is that you are sampling without replacement and just getting a reordering of the list of numbers.  Using `RandomChoice` rather than `RandomSample` will get you sampling with replacement.  (But that's not the only issue here.)

Comment: @JimB With `RandomSample` frequencies are as in the "ideal case" - predicted by the PDF: $\binom nk$ copies of $k$, with size of the sample $2^n$.

Comment: Then why do you even have `RandomSample` if it doesn't matter?  Also, note that you are attempting to estimate two parameters: $n$ and $p$.

Comment: @JimB Yes I admit it is redundant in this case, I just shuffle it to imitate randomness - which is probably foolish as most likely the algorithm does not pay attention to that. As for parameters: since the data are symmetric around the middle, I believe $p$ should be $0.5$ in all cases, and then $n$ is more or less uniquely determined by that.

Comment: If you use `TargetFunctions -> {BinomialDistribution}`, then you get what you think you should get.  I can't tell what approach occurs when `"Discrete"` is used and the documentation doesn't shed any light on it.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have some misunderstandings about the functions you are using.

Suppose `n=3`.  Then

```
n=3;
Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[k, Binomial[n, k]], {k, 0, n}]
```

gets you

```
{0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3}
```

If you apply `RandomSample` to this list, you'll get a random ordering of the elements:  the same number of 1's, the same number of 2's, etc.

`FindDistribution` assumes independence of the observations so among other things order doesn't matter.

So you'll always get

```
BinomialDistribution[4, 0.375]
```

Nothing is wrong with `FindDistribution`.

***Addition:***

Maybe I overstated "Nothing is wrong with `FindDistribution`."

It appears that the documentation could use more details.  Using `TargetFunctions->{BinomialDistribution}` rather than `TargetFunctions->"Discrete"` gets the reasonable results (although I question that almost zero real datasets have the frequencies exactly matching those with `p=1/2`).

```
nn = 14;
data = Join @@ Table[ConstantArray[k, Binomial[nn, k]], {k, 0, nn}];
sol1 = FindDistribution[data, 1, "LogLikelihood", TargetFunctions -> {BinomialDistribution}]
(* {{BinomialDistribution[14, 0.5], -2.04481}} *)
sol2 = FindDistribution[data, 1, "LogLikelihood", TargetFunctions -> "Discrete"]
(* {{BinomialDistribution[17, 0.41605], -2.05258}} *)
```

Also note that the `LogLikelihood` option gives the mean of the individual log likelihood contributions rather than the log of the likelihood:

```
LogLikelihood[BinomialDistribution[sol1[[1, 1, 1]], sol1[[1, 1, 2]]],  data]/Length[data]
(* -2.04481 *)
LogLikelihood[BinomialDistribution[sol2[[1, 1, 1]], sol2[[1, 1, 2]]],   data]/Length[data]
(* -2.05258 *)
```

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding - I've provided additional explanations in the question. I believe in this case `BinomialDistribution[3,0.5]` would be a better guess, no?

Comment: Thanks, the additional explanation is helpful.  But you probably want `RandomChoice` rather than `RandomSample` as the former samples with replacement and the latter samples without replacement (hence you just get a rearrangement of the numbers).  But in any event you're only getting a single sample with a small sample size.  There is going to be considerable variability that is inherent and not the fault of `FindDistribution`.

Comment: Well the sample size increases exponentially, so one would express increasing accuracy - which is not the case. I chose `RandomSample` to have frequencies *exactly* equal to those derived from probabilities

Comment: Sorry, I cannot understand what do you mean by "almost zero real datasets", could you please explain this a little bit more?

Comment: I mean "unrealistic", "contrived", "lacking any practical use", and  "likely useless".  But I certainly could be wrong.  However, there's no indication in the question as to what real-world problem is to be solved with the code you present.  `FindDistribution` does find distributions and parameters but without a method to estimate measures of precision it's not doing a complete and desirable job.

Comment: I see, thanks. I do not see though what exactly makes datasets chosen by me unrealistic.